ylab is not displayed correctly in Boxplot
I want to display two variables in a boxplot T using the code below.
rm(list = ls())
baums = c(3.44,3.32,3.57)
traums = c(2.77,0.99,-2.94,2.75,1.88,1.38,2.83,1.8,0.93,2.69,2.89,0.56,2.61,2.12)

boxplot(baums, traums,   
        at = c(1,2),
        names = c("traums",  "300-50000 m"),
        las = 2,
        col = c("darkgrey","lightgrey"),
        border = "black",
        horizontal = TRUE,
        notch = FALSE
)


The output looks like this:

Since my ylab is very large it is not displayed correctly what can I do so that it is not cut off so strangely.

If it seems interesting at first to put the label on 2 lines, write the names like this :
names = c("traums",  "300-\n50000 m") .

Use the duplicate to make the left margin large enough for your needs. R base graphics do not auto resize margins like ggplot does.
